# Hibernate and oracle issues with timestamps and daylight saving

Tags: hibernate, jpa, timezone

I'm trying to add data to a table in an oracle 11g database with the definition.

```
CREATE TABLE FOO_TIME_TEST  
(ID      NUMBER(20) NOT NULL, TIME    TIMESTAMP(6),
 CONSTRAINT FOO_TIME_TEST_PK   PRIMARY KEY (ID) USING INDEX);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "foo_time_test_idx" ON "FOO_TIME_TEST" (TIME)
```

The Hibernate/JPA mapping using Joda time with the following

```
@Type(type = "com.foo.PersistentDateTime")
@Column(name = "TIME")
public DateTime getTime() {
    return time;
}
```

The mapping class PersistentDateTime relevant bits

```
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object value, int index) throws SQLException {
    if (value == null) {
        Hibernate.TIMESTAMP.nullSafeSet(preparedStatement, null, index);
    } else {
        Hibernate.TIMESTAMP.nullSafeSet(preparedStatement, ((DateTime) value).toDate(), index);
    }
}

public int[] sqlTypes() {
    return new int[] { Types.TIMESTAMP, };
}
```

And the code to write is like this, it was in a loop using plusTime() but I isolated it to these two calls.

```
{
    DateTime time = new DateTime(2012, 10, 28, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC);
    FooTest data = new FooTest();
    data.setTime(time);
    em.persist(data);
    System.out.println(time + " " + time.getMillis() / 1000 / 60 / 60);
}

{
    DateTime time = new DateTime(2012, 10, 28, 1, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC);
    FooTest data = new FooTest();
    data.setTime(time);
    em.persist(data);
    System.out.println(time + " " + time.getMillis() / 1000 / 60 / 60);
}
```

Output

```
2012-10-28T00:00:00.000Z 375384
2012-10-28T01:00:00.000Z 375385

19:23:42,081  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:100 - SQL Error: 1, SQLState: 23000
19:23:42,081 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:101 - ORA-00001: unique constraint (Foo.foo_time_test_idx) violated
```

I've tried removing the unique index, the code then succeeds but the two rows in the database are then the same:

```
ID  Time
1   28-OCT-12 01.00.00.000000000 AM
2   28-OCT-12 01.00.00.000000000 AM
```

With hibernate tracing enabled, it appears to show the two different dates are being flattened to same value.

```
Hibernate: insert into FOO_TIME_TEST (ID, TIME) values (?, ?)
07:38:54,217 TRACE TimestampType:151 - binding '2012-10-28 01:00:00' to parameter: 22
Hibernate: insert into FOO_TIME_TEST (ID, TIME) values (?, ?)
07:38:54,217 TRACE TimestampType:151 - binding '2012-10-28 01:00:00' to parameter: 22
```

Really need source for ojdbc-6.jar to debug further...

I've enabled more debug by downloading the ojdbc6_g.jar for 11.2.0.2.0 and putting in classpath along with the -Doracle.jdbc.Trace=true option as suggested [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/diagnose.htm) and a custom java util log.properties

This provides the additional info after each binding call, in both cases the 01:00 value is shown.

```
Nov 2, 2012 8:20:21 AM oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper setTimestamp
TRACE_30: 3C322E7D Enter: 22, 2012-10-28 01:00:00.0
Nov 2, 2012 8:20:21 AM oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement setTimestamp
FINE: 3C322E7D Public Enter: 22, 2012-10-28 01:00:00.0
Nov 2, 2012 8:20:21 AM oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement setTimestampInternal
FINER: 3C322E7D Enter: 22, 2012-10-28 01:00:00.0
```

Comment: If it still actual:) Could you please show your FooTime class contents? Maybe you already solved that issue?

Answer (score 0):

As you are storing time with time zone I would suggest using the type TIMESTAMP(3) WITH TIME ZONE.

```
CREATE TABLE TIME_TABLE
(
  YOUR_TIME TIMESTAMP(3) WITH TIME ZONE,
  TIME_ZONE  VARCHAR (64 BYTE),
)
```

For hibernate mapping use Joda class org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTimeTZ, below is the XML mapping snippet.

```
<property name="yourTime" type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTimeTZ">
    <column name="YOUR_TIME" />
    <column name="TIME_ZONE" />
</property>
```

I am not familiar with annotation-based Hibernate mapping but I assume it would look something like (I haven't tried it):

```
@Type(type = "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTimeTZ")
@Columns(columns = { @Column(name = "YOUR_TIME"), @Column(name = "TIME_ZONE") })
public DateTime getYourTime() {
        return yourTime;
}
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. I don't recognise the Joda DateTime constructor you are using: it does not seem to have Seconds and Milliseconds arguments.